# sorting of list of list by considering two or three index in python

Tags: python

```
list = [["hasan",6,"bad","chennai"], ["vishnu",7,"good","chennai"], ["tabraiz",8,"good","bangalore"], ["shaik",5,"excellent","chennai"], ["mani",6,"avarage","kerala"], ["cilvin",9,"excellent","chennai"]]
```

given priority as

```
{'excellent':4, 'good':3, 'average':2, 'bad':1}    

list.sort(key=lambda x: (x[3], -x[2], -x[1]))
list.sort(key=lambda x: (x[2], x[0], -x[1]))
list.sort(key=lambda x: (x[2], -x[3], x[0]))
```

These all are working.

but it says

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

when trying to place negative sign in the first position.

ie

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[3], x[2], x[1]))
```

why????

Comment: Unary minus operator works properly, in sorting, with numeric data only.

Comment: Well, is the first element of each sub-list a string? Because that would cause exactly this problem.

Comment: yes, that is why this problem. how to fix it???

Comment: `These all are working.` I do doubt that. Please double check it. To be specific, only `list.sort(key=lambda x: (x[2], x[0], -x[1]))` shall work. Also don't override built-in identifiers like `list`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to order first by `x[3]` in decreasing order, then by `x[2]` in increasing order and then by `x[1]` in increasing order?

Comment: i just said it as an example. Actually the order of sorting will alternate.

Comment: That means, considering the index position and type of sorting will alternate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your method is that `x[3]` is a string, so it does not make sense to do `-x[3]`.

I am not sure there isn't a simpler solution, but you can use [`cmp_to_key`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key), and define your own reversed `key` function:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

l = [['hasan', 6, 'bad', 'chennai'],
     ['vishnu', 7, 'good', 'chennai'],
     ['tabraiz', 8, 'good', 'bangalore'],
     ['shaik', 5, 'excellent', 'chennai'],
     ['mani', 6, 'avarage', 'kerala'],
     ['cilvin', 9, 'excellent', 'chennai']]

rev_key = cmp_to_key(lambda x,y: 1 if x<y else -1 if x>y else 0)
l.sort(key=lambda x: (rev_key(x[3]), x[2], x[1]))
print(l)
```

Result:

```
[['mani', 6, 'avarage', 'kerala'],
 ['hasan', 6, 'bad', 'chennai'],
 ['shaik', 5, 'excellent', 'chennai'],
 ['cilvin', 9, 'excellent', 'chennai'],
 ['vishnu', 7, 'good', 'chennai'],
 ['tabraiz', 8, 'good', 'bangalore']]
```

Note that if you're using Python 2, you can just write:

```
rev_key = cmp_to_key(lambda x,y: cmp(y,x))
```

If you didn't want to sort according to several keys, the right way to go would be to use the `reverse` argument:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[3], reverse=True)
[['mani', 6, 'avarage', 'kerala'],
 ['hasan', 6, 'bad', 'chennai'],
 ['vishnu', 7, 'good', 'chennai'],
 ['shaik', 5, 'excellent', 'chennai'],
 ['cilvin', 9, 'excellent', 'chennai'],
 ['tabraiz', 8, 'good', 'bangalore']]
```